# Double selects one field, how to solve?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

***My project:*** https://bitbucket.org/Chvalov/countrytest/

I can’t understand why the fields `country_code`, `language_code` from the database are selected twice.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        translate0_.country_code as country_3_1_0_,
        translate0_.language_code as language2_1_0_,
        translate0_.country_code as country_3_1_1_,
        translate0_.language_code as language2_1_1_,
        translate0_.translate as translat1_1_1_ 
    from
        country_translate translate0_ 
    where
        translate0_.country_code=?
```

How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Because they are in the `CountryTranslateKey` and in the `CountryTranslate`.

Comment: Yes, because I use annotation `@IdClass`, but in the **CountryTranslateKey** class there are just fields **not marked with JPA annotations**, also tried to do with `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`, result is the same :(

Comment: Tell me how to solve this problem or just use JPQL?